# C++ | Implementing a Stack using STL deque and Adapter design

Tags: c++, stack, deque

Getting ready for an exam and passed upon this question that I cannot confidently answer.
Say we need to implement a Stack using STL deque and an Adapter design, which of the following is the right approach: (There can be only one answer)

```
1. template <typename T> class stack: public deque<T> {};
2. template <typename T> class stack {private: deque<T>* dptr; };
3. template <typename T> class stack {protected: deque<T>* dptr; };
4. template <typename T> class stack {private: deque<T> {};}
5. template <typename T> class stack: private deque<T> {};
6. template <typename T> class stack {protected: deque<T> d; };
```

Any tips for the solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `std::stack` is precisely such an adapter. Feel free to study its design and implementation - its source is included in your C++ installation. For the record, `std::stack` goes with #6 (a protected member), but I don't see any reason why other approaches are obviously wrong.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm aware of that. However, I'm not asked to implement it or use it, i'm just asked which of the options would be the correct approach in case I needed to. I'll check the source ASAP.

Comment: @Flexo Approach #6 is good enough for `std::stack`. What about it strikes you as unacceptable?

Comment: The answer to the above question will depend on the personal preferences of your instructor.  I have my own preferences, but I could see a reasonable argument create a stack that adapts a deque into a stack with each of them, and objections against each of them.  During your class, you where probably communicated your instructors/the class's rules of thumb about the Adapter design (or abstraction in general), and the answer to this question will depend on that information.  And no, there does not have to be a right answer: there has to be a right answer *for your class*.

Comment: @Flexo "`std::stack` doesn't have a protected internal member" Does too. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack : "`Container c` the underlying container (protected member object)"

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik and #Yakk for making this clear.

Comment: A stack should implement `pop`, `push` and `empty` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to publicly inherit from an STL container.  They're simply not designed for it because for "pay as you go" reasons they have no virtual destructor.  Other forms of inheritance are simply creating unnamed members which won't serve you any purpose in this case (they can be useful for using C APIs *etc*).  So that rules out 1 and 5.  So now you can have either a private or protected member.  Choose protected because that leave options open for other classes inheriting from you.  So that leaves 3 and 6.  Now do you want by value or a pointer.  This is an STL container that can happily manage its own resources when destructed, unlike a raw pointer.  So 6 is the clear winner.

Comment: Thank you , simple and clear. And yes, 6 is the correct answer (I just found out).

Comment: @Elia There really is no correct answer.

Comment: Ah yea I understood that, thank you for going to all that trouble explaining how to eliminate every case till the most suitable option remained.